# htaccess fake folder creation challenge

Tags: .htaccess, url

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^postid([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z\-]+).html$ ?post_id=$1
```

I expect:

```
postid1/name-of-post.html
```

the problem is that .htaccess now prefixes every relative url with postid1 as the folder name.

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not .htaccess's doing -  it's the browser thinking it's in a new folder. There's nothing you can do inside .htaccess to fix that, nothing sane anyway.

Use relative paths:

```
../images/image.jpg
```

or absolute paths

```
http://www.domain.com/images/image.jpg
```

instead.

Comment: Thank a lot. I ended up using absolute urls.